# Creating objects with names from string[]

Tags: java, arrays

Hey I'm having some trouble with Java (shocker (sarcasm)).  I have an array of strings, and what I would like to do is iterate through the array, using each string to make a new object.  Is this legal?

```
String[] arrayOfNames = String[3];
goGetNamesToFillTheArray();
for(i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++) {
     Person arrayOfNames[i] = new Person();
}
```

If it's not legal for me to do that, how would I do something like that?

For clarification, I want to have several objects of type person.  If the array contains the entries jon and sally, I could later later in the program have jon.doSomething() as well as sally.doSomething()

Comment: Have you try to run it?

Comment: Just for everybody's knowledge, this is pseudocode.  The problem I'm having is that if I use String as a parameter for Person(), then I end up with one object not the 4 that I need.  It would take Person p and overwrite his name and when I try to reference him, not know which one to pick.

Comment: ellman: Declare the Person array *before* the for loop. Use the length of the String array as the length of the Person array. Come on... you can do this with a little effort. And please post *real* code when asking a question, not sort-of code.

Comment: @ellman121 See one of the answers below...

Comment: You're trying to give variables the names of Strings, and you shouldn't try to do this as this is not how Java works. Variable names are not all that important and certainly not as important as you think they are, but rather ***object references*** are what really matter. If you need to associate an object with a String, use a Map, but I don't think you even need to do this. Just use an array or ArrayList. This same type of question has been asked here umpteen million times, and if you search a little for it, you'll find the same answers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to create an array of Persons and filled them with the names:

```
String[] arrayOfNames = new String[3];
goGetNamesToFillTheArray();
Person[] arrOfPerson = new Person[arrayOfNames.length];
for(int i = 0; i < arrOfPerson.length; i++) {
    arrOfPerson[i] = new Person(arrayOfNames[i]);
}
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly! 1+

Comment: Why is everyone upvoting you and not me?  I posted first, lol.  Nonetheless, I agree (+1).

Comment: @SteveP.: his picture is better.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Lol, I knew that I needed to change my picture.

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

```
String[] arrayOfNames = String[3];
```

is incorrect.  You need to allocate memory via the `new` operator:

```
String[] arrayOfNames = new String[3];
```

To my knowledge, there's no way to dynamically create identifiers.  I have a feeling that what you're actually trying to do is to use the name from your array and in some way use it in `Person`.

To do this, you can have your [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) take a `String` as its parameter.  If you do this, you can change your code to be:

```
goGetNamesToFillTheArray();
Person[] people = new Person[3];

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
     people[i] = new Person(arrayOfNames[i]);
}
```

**NB:**
I used `3` in the above code since you did, but you should use a constant or some sort of variable, ie `final int LENGTH = 3;`.

Answer (score 1):

You should show us the Person class. But conceivably this class will have a constructor that takes a String. Perhaps you should *pass* in the String from the array into the constructor.

Edit: as Ran Eldan **shows** you with his answer. 1+ to that answer!

---

## Edit: Regarding your recent edit to your question:

You state:

> For clarification, I want to have several objects of type person. If the array contains the entries jon and sally, I could later later in the program have jon.doSomething() as well as sally.doSomething()

You're trying to give variables the names of Strings, and you shouldn't try to do this as this is not how Java works. Variable names are not all that important and certainly not as important as you think they are, but rather ***object references*** are what really matter. If you need to associate an object with a String, use a Map, but I don't think you even need to do this. Just use an array or ArrayList. This same type of question has been asked here umpteen million times, and if you search a little for it, you'll find the same answers.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is to create the Object from String class name, You can use code below:

```
String className = "InstanceFromString";
InstanceFromString test = (InstanceFromString)Class.forName(className).newInstance();
System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: Steve P, Yes the question was misleading before editing. Especially subject.